# Chat in Chrome on Windows suddenly doesn't scroll anymore

Tags: bug, chat

In the last 24-48 hours the chat in Chrome on Windows has stopped auto scrolling once it goes off the bottom of the screen.

I tried all the usual fixes after suspecting my cats had hit some key combo breaking things, until a number of other people in Root Access confirmed they were seeing the same thing, with intermittent results (it started working again for some users after they restarted Chrome - this hasn't worked for me).

I'm not seeing the same issue on Linux.

Comment: I'm not insane \o/ - It's really annoying, like how I sometimes page up on irc and don't notice for hours D:

Comment: Hmm, no repro on Chrome dev, might be a Chrome bug that's been fixed. I'll see if I can find one later

Comment: No repro here, though I'm a version or two behind on Chrome. We haven't changed anything in chat lately, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks Adam, Chrome did update for me the other day, now on version: Version 51.0.2704.84 m

Comment: Now on Version 51.0.2704.103 m; no change. Is this something I should raise with Google some how? I'm not a developer and only have limited experience filing bugs so not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, as the dupe indicates (i think i posted first but never mind) it is indeed the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag!